# solve for the max of the sum of two points on a function a given distance apart?

Tags: functions, optimization

I just thought of this concept and am not very experienced in math, so I'm assuming there's an easy solution I'm overlooking.

For a given function y = f(x), how can one find the maximum value for the term 
f(x) + f(x+g)
where g is a specific fixed/predetermined value.

So basically I'm trying to answer this question:
If I am allowed to pick any two points on the graph f(x) which are a distance g apart from each other, how can I find the two points whose sum is higher than any other such sum of points in the function?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how the function is represented.  If you have a nice formula, you can just calculate the sum as a function of $x$.  For example, if $$f(x)=5-x^2\\ f(x+g)=5-(x+g)^2\\ f(x)+f(x+g)=10-2x^2+2xg-g^2$$  You can call that last $h(h)$, take its derivative, set to zero, etc.

Comment: ugh, of course... I never thought to treat the term as a separate function and find its max, lol... thanks